# ChefSpec passed local environment but failed on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, chefspec

I'm running a cookbook and when I run it on my local machine, all of my ChefSpec tests passed. However, when Jenkins ran them, it failed some of my tests. I checked the version of Chef running on both of my local machine and Jenkins server and they were the same. The message I received was a basic one:

> Expected "a directory" with action :create to be in Chef run. Other
>   bash resources: (empty here).

I also have this same test on two platform, redhat linux and aix but only the redhat linux fails.
Anyone has any idea why is it happening? Thank you

Comment: Check that you are running the same versions of Chef and ChefSpec in both places.

Comment: If you have any guards (only_if/not_if/if) in pure ruby, you should mock them. They may return different value locally and on CI.

Comment: @coderanger I checked the version and they are the same both place.

Comment: @SzymonSzypulski I don't think I have any only_if or not _if but maybe my if is messing up. Thank you for the suggestion.